# Sockets in Linux - how do I know the client has finished?

Tags: c++, linux, http, sockets

I am currently trying to implement my own webserver in C++ - not for productive use, but for learning.

I basically open a socket, listen, wait for a connection and open a new socket from which I read the data sent by the client. So far so good. But how do I know the client has finished sending data and not simply temporarily stopped sending more because of some other reason?

My current example: When the client sends a POST-request, it first sends the headers, then two times "\r\n" in a row and then the request body. Sometimes the body does not contain any data. So if the client is temporarily unable to send anything after it sent the headers - how do I know it is not yet finished with its request?

Does this solely depend on the used protocol (HTTP) and it is my task to find this out on the basis of the data I received, or is there something like an EOF for sockets?

If I cannot get the necessary Information from the socket, how do I protect my program from faulty clients? (Which I guess I must do regardless of this, since it might be an attacker and not a faulty client sending wrong data.) Is my only option to keep reading until the request is complete by definition of the protocol or a timeout (defined by me) is reached?

I hope this makes sense.

Btw: Please don't tell me to use some library - I want to learn the basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The protocol (HTTP) tells you when the client has stopped sending data.  You can't get the info from the socket as the client will leave it open waiting for a response.

As you say, you must guard against errant clients not sending proper requests.  Typically in the case of an incomplete request a timeout is applied to the read.  If you haven't received anything in 30 seconds, say, then close the socket and ignore it.

For an HTTP post, there should be a header (Content-Length) saying how many bytes to expect after the the end of the headers.  If its a POST and there is no Content-Length, then reject it.

Comment: Thank you. This means my current "workaround" is actually the way to go. :-)

Answer (score 1):

> "Does this solely depend on the used protocol (HTTP) and it is my task to find this out on the basis of the data I received,"

Correct. You can find the HTTP spec via google; 
http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html

> "or is there something like an EOF for sockets?"

There is as it behaves just like a file ... but that's not applicable here because the client isn't closing the connection; you're sending the reply ON that connection.

Comment: Not exactly true. Client is allowed to half-close the connection, using e.g. shutdown(). In such case server gets EOF condition while reading from the socket, but writing to the socket is still possible.

Comment: Which would go against the HTTP 1.1 spec which says a client should maintain a persistent connection.

Comment: RFC says about *server* maintaining a persistent connection. I don't think there's anything in RFC2616 stopping the client from half-closing the connection, when there's nothing more to send.

Comment: Not to point out the obvious, but think about that for a moment and explain the point of a persisted connection where the client can't send additional requests. The excpetion is a long poll, but regardless the point is, you have to specify a content length in the header, EOF does not mean end of message body and in fact the server is probably well within its rights to disco a client on EOF since I don't see that in the RFC either.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear enough - I'm not saying that the client half-closes the connection after each and every request, that would render persistent connection idea useless, obviously. Of course, I agree that content length is used to detect end of the body part. However, I believe that the client is allowed to half-close the connection after sending the request, if it knows that particular request is the last one. In such case the server will read headers and body, send it's response over half-closed connection, try to read another request, get EOF instead and close the socket.

Comment: BTW, RFC2616 is not very clear about such scenarios. IMHO it should be specified much more precisely.

Answer (score 1):

With text based protocols like HTTP you are at the mercy of the client. Most well formatted POST will have a content-length so you know how much data is coming. However the client can just delay sending the data, or it may have had its Ethernet cable removed or just hang, in which case that socket is sitting there indefinitely. If it disconnects nicely then you will get a socket closed event/response from the recv().

Most well designed servers in that case will have a receive timeout, and if the socket is idle for more than say 30 seconds it will close that socket, so resources are not leaked by misbehaving clients.